# Solr , after document finding relevant field

Tags: solr

I stuck in a problem . Suppose my schema is like this

```
locality     sublocality    park
WhiteField   subField       jhonsonPark
M.G Bay      M.G. Palace    WhitePark
```

Now , I have created a search box , where user can enter any string , then I have to search it in above two documents and displaying result to user . 
My problem is , I can do search on 3 fields with 'fq' macro , but which field should I display .. 
Suppose my query is 'son' , then i will get record 1 with more score (because it matches 'jhonson') than document 2 , But how would I know, because of which field document 1 got high score ?
I hope you would have understood my problem. I am able to search on multiple fields but unable to show relevant field ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr does not return only the field that matched the query.
It would return you all the fields for the document which are marked by the fl parameter.
If you want to check which field the query matched you can check

1. highlighting feature which would give you the field and the match
2. You can enable debug query and the explanation would give you the match for the fields.

However, both the options can be just used for checking purpose and not the actual search as it will be expensive for performance as well as may also depend on the configuration